# Update post status from “publish” to “trash” prior to year 2018

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-cron, post-status

I want to update all posts with status from published to trashed or delete permanently. whose published date is 2018 and previous using WordPress cronjob.

Example:
If I have 209085 posts, 500 posts can be trashed or delete permanently during each cronjob run.

Comment: Have you considered doing this with WP CLI instead? It could be done without writing any PHP and hooked up to a real server cron job, sidestepping timeout issues

Comment: I don't have access to server CLI, therefore, this is out of the question. It must be done using the theme's function file.

Comment: That's a shame about WP CLI, but I'd at least insist that it be done via a plugin, themes are for visuals and styling, anything else goes in a plugin. Keep in mind you could download the database to a local install, run WP CLI on your computer, then upload the result to the server

Comment: @TomJNowell can you help me out with the plugin then?

Comment: Here's [wp_trash_post](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.2/wp-includes/post.php#L2945). It's pretty simple. If you definitely don't have any pre_trash_post, wp_trash_post or trashed_post handlers then you can just do this with SQL directly in the database: update the post status to 'trash' and any comments to status 'post_trashed', and add the trash timestamp meta if you want too.

Comment: But if you do want to do this as a cron job, then you just need to 1) set up a cron job, 2) find 500 posts <= 2018 3) call wp_trash_post on each one. It should be easy to find examples for the cron job and search.